# how can I get a new list from a list by a keyword?

Tags: python, list

```
list1=[['a1',1,2,3],['b1',4,5,6],['a2',1,2,3],['b2',4,5,6]...['a10',1,2,3],['b10',4,5,6]]
```

how can I get a new `list2=[['a1',1,2,3],['a2',1,2,3]...['a10',1,2,3]]` by keyword '`a`' in python?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want but you should use a filter or a list comprehension.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list2 = [item for item in list1 if item[0].startswith('a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
list2 = filter(lambda item: item[0].startswith("a")  , list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative you may wish to consider if you're going to be filtering that list a lot:

```
from collections import defaultdict
keyword = defaultdict(list)
for item in list1:
    keyword[item[0][0]].append(item)
```

This then gives you a `dict` where you can access the items via `keyword['a']` or `keyword['b']` for instance...